# r for loop in dataframe

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a for loop calculating fields in a dataframe, averaging out the difference over missing data over several rows.  I used:

```
for(l in i:k-1){data[l,j]=as.numeric(data[l-1,j])+increase}
```

intending to change the fields from i to k-1
what happens is that fields from i-1 to k get changed -- is this what R should do?

I appreciate that I can get the results I really want by enclosing the k-1 in brackets (as I did in the first for loop below), but don't understand why R is interpreting my i:k-1 as i-1:k (see the second loop).

Example:

```
> data[l,j]=0
> data[l-1,j]=0
> data[l+1,j]=0
> increase
[1] -2.8
> i
[1] 11019
> k
[1] 11020
> for(l in i:(k-1)){data[l,j]=as.numeric(data[l-1,j])+increase}
> data[l-1,j]
[1] "0"
> data[l+1,j]
[1] "0"
> data[l,j]
[1] "-2.8"
> data[l,j]=0
> for(l in i:k-1){data[l,j]=as.numeric(data[l-1,j])+increase}
> data[l,j]
[1] "7.7"
> data[l+1,j]
[1] "0"
> data[l-1,j]
[1] "10.5"
> data[l-2,j]
[1] "11.1"
```

Comment: [Order of operations](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Syntax.html). Compare `1:4-1` with `1:(4-1)`. (Note that `:` is *before* `-` substract.)

Comment: Yes, interestingly the `:` resides right between exponents and multiply/divide in the R order of operations (BECDMAS, I guess?). So `1:5^2` returns `[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25` while `1:5*5` returns `[1]  5 10 15 20 25`.

Comment: It would be more efficient to do this without a for loop: `data[i:(k-1),j] <- as.numeric(data[(i-1),j]) + increase * (1:(k-i))`.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Richard, for the explanation David & the more efficient method jos -- I am new to R but have long experience in low level languages & tend to spell it out the long way.